# semantic HTML5 CSS3 responsive design

Tags: html, css

After reading a number of books on responsive web design with `HTML5` and `CCS3` I started to search for example templates to play around with.

However, everything I come across seems to use a `CSS` grid which I am unfamiliar with. There are many frameworks available which all seem to use a grid system.  When I look at the source code it seems to go against everything I have read about.  They are still using `divs` and not using any HTML5 tags like  and  and therefore are non-semantic.  I want to build responsive website without a `CSS` grid so that it is semantic.  Can anyone help on where I start with this? I would love to see an example a responsive web page that does not use a grid system.

I would rather build from scratch than use a framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can still place HTML5 semantic markup inside of markup that has no semantics, for example, your `article` element can be surrounded by meaningless `div` elements.

Having said this, you don't have to start with a framework at all - but my advice is to limit the number of elements you need to change sizes on to make things responsive. For example, if you set widths on 10 elements, it is going to become painful. If you can set the width on one element and have all the child elements expressed as a percentage it will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but Im looking for examples really, I have read lots and lots on the subject but am looking for examples to help get me started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the frameworks are going against everything you have read about with semantic HTML 5 tags. It's just the fact the frameworks don't have content, and content is what drives using a `<section>`, `<article>`, `<header>`, ect. over a plain `<div>` tag. As the developer you are the one who brings semantic meaning to the code by using the HTML 5 tags.

I have found the only way to really get a good feel for how responsive design works is to dive in and get coding. Create a simple layout and apply different media queries and get used to using percentages vs. fixed widths. I bet after you get through a couple pages you'll start to feel more comfortable with it, and it will become much easier to plan on how you will layout your site.

Since every site is going to be different I don't see what kind of examples you are hoping that people are going to provide you with for you to use as a starting point. If you are not using a framework and coding from scratch I suggest this set of media queries to start with: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/